# Polar expedition to Saturn

Tags: mathematics, visual

<sub>[(NASA)](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap130220.html)
            
            
[(OMCA)](http://collections.museumca.org/?q=collection-item/20105418820)</sub>


[image]
 
[image]

     
Saturn’s north pole has a hexagonal cloud boundary
       
Why we must go there

While deciding on our next home planet, let’s examine a
**mystery function** $\boldsymbol{f(x,y)}$
discovered by a mathematical expedition
to the hexagonal weather pattern on Saturn’s topside.

A positive test,  $f(x,y) = {\scriptsize\raise.4ex+}1 \kern1mu$,
indicates an evenly triangular array of points above the clouds.

[image: pizza.and.1]

A subsurface probe, 
$f(x,y) = -{\large\tfrac54} \kern1mu$,
reveals a regular hexagonal array of points.
 
But we need a modulated survey, 
$ f(x,y) = 1 {+} \, 3 \cos{\tiny\sqrt{\vphantom{\raise3.5ex~}\normalsize3}}
                                                        \kern2mu r \kern1mu $,
in order to account for the satellite view.

[image: -1.25.and.1+3cosV3r]

As this is part of a polar expedition, 
$r = \sqrt{x^2 \! + y^2} \,$
and that last equation is the same as 
$ f(x,y) = 1 {+} \, 3 \cos \! \sqrt{3 (x^2 \! + y^2)} \kern1mu
  \LARGE\raise-.4ex\strut $.
 
Its $y$- intercepts are difficult to specify
but it crosses 
$y = 0 \,$ at 
$ \require{begingroup}\begingroup
   \def \3  {{ \tiny\sqrt{ \vphantom{\raise3ex~}\large 3 } }}
    \def \X#1{ {\pm}{ \large\tfrac{#1\pi}{3\3} \normalsize\,\raise.5ex{,} \, } }
      x = \X{ 2} \X{ 4} \X{ 8} \X{10} \X{14} \X{16} ~ \cdots
      \endgroup $

Laboratory measurements have determined that
$f(x,y)$
contains **10** secret ingredients,
each of which may be
a variable, an operator, a trigonometric function,
a decimal number, a symbolic constant,
or a single bracket / fence
such as left parenthesis, right brace, or absolute value bar.
For example,
$ 1 {+} \, 3 \cos \! \sqrt{3 (x^2 \! + y^2)} \, $
contains **13** ingredients.

> So . . .
>         
>   **What is a 10 - ingredient formula for
>     $~\boldsymbol{ f(x,y) }\,$?**

In the spirit of scientific methodology,
feel free to request a plot based on
$f(x,y)$.
 
Another modulation, 
$ f(x,y) = -\sin^2 \!{ \tfrac{\large 2}
                             { \tfrac1{\large r} - \tfrac{1}{6\large\pi} } }\, $
for instance, can uncover some nuts and bolts.

[image: -sin2over6pi]

**Notes**

Although $r$, $\theta$ and non-trigonometric functions
are not available as ingredients within $f(x,y)$,
any solutions that use them anyway would be more than welcome
for the sake of interest and education.

The cartoonish “points” in plots of 
$f(x,y) = {\scriptsize\raise.4ex+}1 \,$ and 
$f(x,y) = -{\large\tfrac54} \,$         represent true points.

Complex numbers are allowed but not needed.

These implicit plots were made by
[EquationExplorer
 at KevinMehall.net](https://kevinmehall.net/p/equationexplorer/).

Also good for implicit function plots is
[MathGrapher at eMathHelp](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/).

Comment: Would you like to clarify whether those things that look like little circles in e.g. the plot of f(x,y)=1 are *actually* little (approximate) circles or single points? (The, er, point of my question is the point versus nontrivial-contour distinction; I'm not asking whether they're really circle-like versus e.g. figure-eight-like.)

Comment: Is $r$ available as a "cost 1" variable in the expression for $f$, and if so do we also have $\theta$? Or do we have only $x,y$?

Comment: Am I right in understanding that *any* number/constant costs us only 1 unit? E.g., if I wanted $\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac{5\pi}{e^2}$ would that have cost 1?

Comment: Are there any particular rules on (1) what functions we're allowed to use (obviously trig, exp, log; what else?) and/or (2) when they need parens around their arguments?

Comment: If we want to say "absolute value of ...", can we do it with vertical bars |x| counting each bar as a sort of funny bracket? Or should we assume there's an abs function we can invoke? Or is it just not allowed?

Comment: (I guess there's always $\sqrt{x^2}$ for that purpose, unless of course complex numbers are involved.)

Comment: Incidentally, are complex numbers allowed? If so, do we have functions like real part, imaginary part, argument?

Comment: Thank you for taking an interest in this, @Gareth McCaughan.
**I'd be tickled pink and learn something
  from seeing even similar plots produced otherwise,
  with any number of ingredients,**
but until these clarifications make it into the puzzle statement:
i)  Those dots are true points.
ii) $r$ and $\theta$ are not available as such, though I'd love to see
    a solution that takes them for granted anyway.
iii) $\large\tfrac2{\surd3}{+}\tfrac{5\pi}{e^2}$ would be 10 ingredients;
    "constant" is meant as $e$,$i$,$\pi$,$\varphi$,... .
[continued next comment]

Comment: [continued]
iv) Only trig functions were used, in the familiar way where parentheses are often omitted; I might as well limit the statement to allow only them,
    in order to avert doubt about how familiar a function
    needs to be;
    do feel free to show off some obscure functions
    as sidelights in any case.
v)  Absolute value | | bars count as 2 ingredients;
    I've never seen an $\rm abs$ function in mathematics
    but suppose it could be used like a trig function
    to save an ingredient.
vi) Complex numbers are allowed but not needed;
    the plots are purely real.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula is

> $f(x,y) = \cos y \cos \sqrt{3}x - \sin^2 y$.

As with @humn's similar [find-the-formula puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49948/making-waves-at-your-friendly-function-foundry) from a few weeks ago, my path to the solution was rather ad hoc and unprincipled, though with hindsight I can see better routes I could have taken.

Obviously it's got to be

> some sort of trigonometrical thing with appropriate symmetries. However, the "obvious" ways to construct these came up blank both because I couldn't get the right values and because I couldn't get them short enough.

So the next thing for this pure-mathematician-turned-hacker-and-engineer to do was

> to figure out as many values of $f$ as possible from the diagrams, kludge together some sort of trigonometrical abomination, and see what happens.

Well,

> first of all consider the line $y=0$. Obviously we have something here with period $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}$ which I'll call $p$. We know that it's 1 at $x=0$, and from the first "modulated survey" we see that it's $-\frac12$ at $x=p/3$ and $2p/3$. This, together with known symmetries, is actually enough, but looking at the "nuts and bolts" plot shows us pretty well where the contours of $f=0$ and $f=-1$ are; in particular, $f(p/4)=f(3p/4)=0$ and $f(p/2)=-1$. [Here is one of those better routes: the contours of $f=-1$ are straight lines, and it's pretty obvious where they are, and I think following this line of thought would get us there much quicker than what I actually did.] And this is *really* enough even for an idiot like me to see that $f(x,0)$ is surely $\cos \sqrt{3}x$.

Now let's look at

> what happens along the lines $y=\frac{\pi}3$ and $y=\frac{2\pi}3$. We expect to get something of the form $A(y)\cos\sqrt{3}x+B(y)$ where of course $A,B$ will themselves be trigonometric functions, with period $2\pi$ or some factor thereof. What we know here is that $f((1+2k)p/6,\pi/3)$ goes $-\frac12,-\frac54,-\frac12$ for $k=0,1,2$, and that's enough to give us $A=\frac12$ and $B=-\frac34$. Similarly, at $y=\frac{2\pi}3$ we get $A=-\frac12$ and $B=-\frac34$. At $y=0$ we already know $A=1$ and $B=0$; and at $y=\pi$ we readily see $A=-1$ and $B=0$. And now it's pretty clear that $A(y)=\cos y$ and $B(y)=\sin^2y$, and we're done.

The form of $f$ is a bit surprising at first glance. It's not immediately apparent that it has the symmetries we want. What's going on?

> Well, taking a hint from the remark above about the contours of $f=-1$, let's rewrite it as $f(x,y)=\cos y\cos\sqrt3x-1+\cos^2y$. Now we can factorize: $f(x,y)=-1+\cos y(\cos\sqrt3x+\cos y)$. And now we can apply one of those sum-to-product rewrites we learned in secondary school and then forgot: $f(x,y)=-1+2\cos y\cos(y-\sqrt3x)\cos(y+\sqrt3x)$. And *this* does obviously have the symmetries we want.